# How to make sure NSWindows always fit on (small) screen?

Tags: objective-c, macos

I'm writing a piece of code to make sure a NSWindow that I create will always fit on the screen. But when I set the screen to some thing low resolution (1024 x 640), my windows is still a little bit higher than the actual screen, resulting in the lower part of the windows to be outsize the screen and hence, not viewable. Here is my code:

```
NSWindowStyleMask style_mask = NSWindowStyleMaskTitled
                             | NSWindowStyleMaskClosable
                             | NSWindowStyleMaskDocModalWindow;
int visible_width = [[NSScreen mainScreen] visibleFrame].size.width;
int visible_height = [[NSScreen mainScreen] visibleFrame].size.height;

int width = std::min(visible_width, kDefaultWindowWidth);
int height = std::min(visible_height, kDefaultWindowHeight);

NSRect frame_rect = NSMakeRect(0, 0, width, height);
NSRect content_rect = [NSWindow
    contentRectForFrameRect:frame_rect
                  styleMask:style_mask];

_myWindow = [[NSWindow alloc]
    initWithContentRect:content_rect
               styleMask:style_mask
                backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered
                  defer:NO];
```

The problem is, after this code, `content_rect` has the same size as the `frame_rect`, as if the window would not have a title. In reality, when I create the window, it does have a title (as expected). Did I do anything wrong?

Comment: I tried both frameRectForContentRect::styleMask (the class method) as well as frameRectForContentRect (the instant method, called after creating NSWindow), and still the frame_rect and content_rect are of the same size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is `NSWindowStyleMaskDocModalWindow`. I don't know what you think it means, but whatever you think it means, it doesn't mean that. Delete it.

Comment: That works. Thanks a lot. For the record, I thought it means my windows will be modal.

Comment: A window is modal if you present it modally (e.g. you call `runModal`).

Comment: Yes, I did call runModal at the end to make it modal. But at first I thought (incorrectly apparently), that I should set that NSWindowStyleMaskDocModalWindow in style for the measurement.

Comment: A document modal window is a sheet. Sheets have no title bar.